# JSON schema - how to define types that depend on values elsewhere in file

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given that I have a JSON file something like this:

```html
{
  "organisation":"Acme Co. Ltd",
  "organisation_abbreviation":"acme",
  "document_types":["invoice","credit-note"],
  "invoice":{
    "date":"2017-05-31",
    "value":238.44,
    "description":"invoice for xxx"
  },
  "credit_note":{
    "date":"2017-05-22",
    "value":0.0,
    "description":"DNOTE for xxx"
  },
}
```

The salient being that in document types, I define the various permitted document types, and then later down I have a section for each of the document types named here.

How can I write a schema validation that will check that each document type section is a one of the types mentioned above (the example would fail because 'credit-note' != 'credit_note')

Answer (score 0):

Would that fill what you need by using the OneOf:

```
{
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

      "title": "Acme billing",
      "type" : "object",
      "definitions": {
        "Entry": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
             "date": "string",
             "value": "number",
             "description": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "organisation": "string",
        "organisation_abbreviation": "string",
        "document_types": {
          "enum": ["invoice","credit-note"]
        }
        "oneOf" : [{
          "properties": {
            "invoice": {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Entry"
            },
            "credit-note":{
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Entry"
            }
          ]
       },
       "additionalProperties":false
     }
   }
```

}